# How would pinchers have to evolve to better manipulate tools?

Tags: biology, evolution

I'm thinking about an alien race that evolved from large terrestrial crustaceans and has developed a somewhat large brain. Like crabs on earth, these creatures have pinchers wich they use for self defence and picking food, but they also use them to move around sticks and rocks to build a small nest for their young. Now, I'm thinking that this species becomes sentient in the far future and starts developing civilization. There's a problem though. To my knowledge, in order for a species to develop civilization it needs to be able to manipulate tools easily, either through the use of hands with a prehensile thumb or maybe a tentacle. But crabs pinchers have very little mobility outher that opening and closing. How could pinchers evolve in order to better manipulate objects in their environment?

Comment: from google i found this [dresser crab](https://www.mnn.com/earth-matters/wilderness-resources/photos/15-remarkable-animals-that-use-tools/dresser-crab)

Comment: though i cant think of what object or tools cant be wielded using pincer, at least crab can wield knife from what i found. like [this one](https://i.insider.com/5abbc3ec42e1cc3a4e16d3f7?width=1100&format=jpeg&auto=webp) and [this one](https://i.insider.com/5abbc3eb42e1cc3a4e16d3f5?width=960&format=jpeg)

Answer (score 3):

Duplication. Since we're talking aliens, even terrestrial-derived ones, they simply can have more claws. additional smaller claws mean you can just lay another 'hand' on something if you need finer control. Primary claws can be bigger for gross motor manipulation (crushing human skulls or opening coconuts, as needed) while smaller ones delicately manipulate.

Comment: Like a [Tokummia katalepsis](http://www.sci-news.com/paleontology/tokummia-katalepsis-cambrian-marine-predator-04820.html)'s fifty legs, many with a claw appendage, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

You could have them evolve from crabs with mutated claws with more than 2 pincers per claw. We do see lobsters and crabs with additional pincers, although the extra pincer is usually quite useless, your species could have a third pincer that acts like a thumb.

[image]

This might still not give them the range of motion needed, extra limbs as others have mentioned is a good solution but you could also re design the arm to add more joints, similar to factory robots that have a great range of potion and accuracy due to their joints.

[image]

Comment: Hmm...opposable pincers! That would do it!

Answer (score 3):

The downside of an exoskeleton is limited range of motion, realistically there is not much you can do just because of how crab limbs form developmentally.

Your best bet to to change some of the other legs into extra pincers, which will give a much larger range of motion by working together. As an up side, this mutation occasionally occurs already, you just need to specialize the different claws.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They could go the route of the fiddler crab.

[image]

With one claw specialized for fighting and the other for manipulation.

In terms of doing fine detail work though I don't think they would need to adapt their claw, instead they would use their mouths.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod_mouthparts

They have a wide range of designs already with several including manipulating elements. They could adapt them to do more detailed work. This would give them one grasping claw, one manipulating claw and then their mouth for anything fine.

They might adjust their eyes so they can see what they are doing with their mouth, or just use other senses for that purpose.

Comment: I agree evolved mouth pieces cold make good manipulators. The mouth might need evolving  to get tool-user ready, but that's the premise, after all.